# How to sort the table based on the values (time stamp ) of a column

Tags: angular, sorting, timestamp, angular-material-table

I have table one of whose column is  `uploadedOn`:
[image: Table]

[1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tntvst?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts): https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ6wh.png. I want to sort the rows of the table based on the time stamp of the `uploadedOn` column.
I wrote this piece of code

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="uploadedOn">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by request timestamp">Uploaded On</th> 
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.uploadedOn | date:'MM/dd/YYYY, hh:mm:ss aa'}}</td>
    </ng-container>
```

But this didn't work.Can someone tell me the way to sort the table ?That is the rows which have a recent `UploadedOn` value appear on the top(chronological order).

```
<div class="avails-set-table" *ngIf="availSetsLoaded">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="inputAvailsList" multiTemplateDataRows matSort matSortActive="uploadedOn" matSortDirection="asc">
```

I even tried this but even this didn't work. I want the table to have those rows at first which have recent yr, and then based on the recent month.. and so on ..

Please find attached the [stackbiltz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tntvst?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: check the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting) but remember that to work the "sort" the dataSource should be a MatTableDataSource and asign the property sort that you get it with a ViewChild

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the table by default using `matSortActive` and `matSortDirection`

```html
<table matSort matSortActive="uploadedOn" matSortDirection="asc">
```

or in typescript:

```js
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort

...
...

this.sort.sort(({ id: 'uploadedOn', start: 'asc'}) as MatSortable);
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

Please find attached the [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tntvst?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I tried the first one. It didnt' help

Comment: Share your code or a static example on https://stackblitz.com/ to see what are you doing!

Comment: kindly see .I have attached the link.